# Unknown error code [5204] when running job on IBM's qasm_simulator

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am submitting a job to ibmq_qasm_simulator and after the validation I repeatedly get the error "**Error running job on a simulator. [5204]**" The site with error descriptions https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/manage/errors **does not have an entry** for the error code 5204, so it is impossible to know what causes the error and how to fix it. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: do you have an example of the code that you are running so we can try to reproduce the error that you get?

Comment: It is an implementation of the one-hot encoding presented in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09314 using 30 qubits. The same code works for 20 qubits without any problems.

Comment: Does `job.error_message()` give you more information?

Comment: This is the error message:  
  
Traceback (most recent call last):print("error message = ", job.error_message())  

File ".conda/envs/qiskit_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/job/ibmqjob.py", line 524, in error_message  self._retrieve_result()  

File "..../job/ibmqjob.py", line 914, in _retrieve_result  self._set_result(result_response)  

File "...../job/ibmqjob.py", line 956, in _set_result  

'job {}: {}'.format(self.job_id(), str(err))) from err  

qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.exceptions.IBMQJobApiError: "Unable to retrieve result for job ....: 'results'"

Comment: Unfortunately 5204 is a generic error that basically just says something went wrong. It's usually a network error somewhere in the cloud. Since it's been a few days, you can try again and see if it works now. If not, you'll need to contact an IQX admin either through slack or the "feedback" button on IQX to look up your particular job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help tracking this down. For future reference, the culprit was the usage of the function [QuantumCircuit.initialize(params, qubits)](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.initialize.html), which triggered an error out of some reason. Not sure why it fails in this case but not in others. The solution was to implement what the initialize function was supposed to do with basis gates.